# Why is this += loop faster than the equivalent = loop?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, profiling, disassembly

I wrote this simple loop in C++ (Visual Studio 2019 in Release mode) that goes through one million 32-bit integers and assigns each to the previous:

```
    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
        ints32[i - 1] = ints32[i];
```

And here's a loop that's the same except it uses `+=`:

```
    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
        ints32[i - 1] += ints32[i];
```

I'm measuring both of these functions by running them 20 times, discarding the 5 slowest and 5 fastest runs, and averaging the rest. (Before each measurement, I fill the array with random integers.) I find that the assign-only loop takes around 460 microseconds, but the loop with addition takes 320 microseconds. These measurements are consistent across multiple runs (they vary a bit, but the addition is always faster), **even when I change the order** in which I measure the two functions.

Why is the loop with addition faster than the loop without addition? I would think the addition would make it take longer, if anything.

Here is the disassembly, and you can see that the functions are equivalent except that the addition loop does more work (and sets `eax` to `ints[i - 1]` instead of `ints[i]`).

```
    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
00541670 B8 1C 87 54 00       mov         eax,54871Ch  
        ints32[i - 1] = ints32[i];
00541675 8B 08                mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00541677 89 48 FC             mov         dword ptr [eax-4],ecx  
0054167A 83 C0 04             add         eax,4  
0054167D 3D 18 90 91 00       cmp         eax,offset floats32 (0919018h)  
00541682 7C F1                jl          IntAssignment32+5h (0541675h)  
}
00541684 C3                   ret  

    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
00541700 B8 18 87 54 00       mov         eax,offset ints32 (0548718h)  
        ints32[i - 1] += ints32[i];
00541705 8B 08                mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00541707 03 48 04             add         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
0054170A 89 08                mov         dword ptr [eax],ecx  
0054170C 83 C0 04             add         eax,4  
0054170F 3D 14 90 91 00       cmp         eax,919014h  
00541714 7C EF                jl          IntAddition32+5h (0541705h)  
}
00541716 C3                   ret
```

(The int array is `volatile` because I didn't want the compiler to optimize it away or vectorize it or anything, and indeed the disassembly it's producing is what I wanted to measure.)

---

Edit: I'm noticing that when I change seemingly unrelated things about the program, the assignment version gets faster, and then slower again. I suspect it may be related to the alignment of the function's code, maybe?

I'm using the default Visual Studio 2019 Win32 Release compiler options (copied this from the project properties):

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "Release\" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\profile.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Compiler version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.15

Here's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

const int ValueRange = 100000000;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution< int > distribution( 1, ValueRange - 1 );

const int Iters = 1000000; // nanoseconds -> milliseconds

volatile int ints32[Iters];

void InitArrayInt32()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < Iters; i++ )
        ints32[i] = distribution( generator );
}

const int SampleCount = 20;
const int KeepSampleCount = SampleCount - 2 * (SampleCount / 4);

float ProfileFunction( void(*setup)(), void(*func)() )
{
    uint64_t times[SampleCount];

    for ( int i = 0; i < SampleCount; i++ )
    {
        setup();

        auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        func();

        auto endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        times[i] = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count();
    }

    std::sort( times, times + SampleCount );
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for ( int i = SampleCount / 4; i < SampleCount - SampleCount / 4; i++ )
        total += times[i];
    return total * (1.0f / KeepSampleCount);
}

void IntAssignment32()
{
    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
        ints32[i - 1] = ints32[i];
}
void IntAddition32()
{
    for ( int i = 1; i < Iters; i++ )
        ints32[i - 1] += ints32[i];
}

int main()
{
    float assignment = ProfileFunction( InitArrayInt32, IntAssignment32 );
    float addition = ProfileFunction( InitArrayInt32, IntAddition32 );
    printf( "assignment: %g\n", assignment );
    printf( "addition: %g\n", addition );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler options did you use?

Comment: Invert the order of loops (memory is hot, in cache).

Comment: @lorro OP says he already tried to switch the order and the result remains consistent.

Comment: `I'm measuring both of these functions by running them 20 times` how exactly do you measure the loops? Also, what compilers and options do you use here?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind ok, I overlooked that. Still, I'm voting for checking cache effect: the first code loads at `[eax]` then at `[eax-4]`, thus cache is likely loaded from `[eax]`; whereas in the second case, the reads are first `[eax]` and then `[eax+4]`, i.e., in order.

Comment: When doing  microbenchmarking, a full [MCVE] is needed.  Because there are thousands of ways to mess up a microbenchmark, and by far the most likely reason why you get the results you do is artifacts of how you did your microbenchmark.  Most people assume they did it right, and most people are wrong; the odds you are the one person who didn't mess up a microbenchmark should be unlikely even to yourself.

Comment: While attempting to write an answer to some of these questions, I noticed that changing seemingly unrelated things about the program (like the printf that shows me the results) was causing the results to change. I got better performance in the assignment loop (280 microseconds), then it switched back to slow and to fast again as I changed things. I suspect it might be related to the alignment of the function in memory. Note in the disassembly I posted, the assignment function straddles a 128 byte boundary. So maybe that's the problem. Is there a way to make VS align functions better?

Comment: I added the full code to the question.

Comment: Your program is pretty fast for a benchmark. The frequency of modern processors is dynamic so it is better to have a loop in the main function. Something like >=5 iteration. At least to see if timings are *stable* during a given execution and between so to understand possible sources of variation. On my i5-9600KF PC with GCC (O3) I got consistent results: the addition is always slower (10-15%).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wrote [my own benchmark](https://godbolt.org/z/xs5n5Wsca) before you had posted yours, and have been playing around with it a bit. From what I can tell, there can be a fair bit of variation in the clock itself due to process scheduling. And so even your quartile sampling does not give a completely accurate picture. For a proper measurement, you should be outputting _all_ your timings and graphing them. You'll likely see that you need better statistical metrics. You should see a shift in the timings curve that matches what you would expect.

Comment: @lorro The order probably doesn't matter here, since in any case both addresses are either part of the same cache word, or consecutive cache words, and the total number of cache words array occupies (and, thus, is accessed) is the same.

Comment: A few gotchas.  (1) you do one test before the other on the same memory.  Hot/cold memory is going to add a bias.  (2) you are measuring averages; you should describe the distribution.  If the distribution within one of them is larger than the difference, it is a sign of a problem.  (3) I'd use a high precision clock instead of a steady one.  It could go backwards, yes, but it is unlikely, and precision could matter here.  Microseconds are small.  Also, test for granularity of your clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: I'm noticing that when I change seemingly unrelated things about the program, the assignment version gets faster, and then slower again. I suspect it may be related to the alignment of the function's code, maybe?

The reason why one is faster then the other is luck. The variance in speed caused by the alignment of the code and the data has far more influence than the minor difference in the generated code.

Even though you measure multiple times what you measure is always the same alignment (to some degree if you have address space randomization). This eliminates the noise from the scheduler and interrupts but not the noise from alignment changes.

But when you change something in the code you change the alignment, e.g. shift the array by 4 byte. Of shift the code by 1 byte. And that has actually a larger impact to the speed than the difference between -O0 and -O2 in gcc. There are lots of papers on this effect and more.